# When accessing my NSMutableArray I get an error message like "Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'id'"

Tags: objective-c

I have the following function and I am struggling to get the y value out as an int.

```
+ (NSMutableArray *) cleanPoints:(NSMutableArray *)pointsArray{

NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i<pointsArray.count-1; i++){

    CLog(@"pointsArray %@", pointsArray[i]);   /// here it gives me the correct number, like 345

    int y = (int)pointsArray[i];    //// here seems to be the problem
    CLog(@"y = %d", y);     ///// y is a weird number, like y = 384643392

    if (y < 4 || y > -4){
        y = 0;
    }

    //create Array
    [mutableArray addObject:@(y)];

    }
    return mutableArray;
}
```

If I take out the (int) from the int y = (int)pointsArray[I] line then I get the error "Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

```
int y = (int)pointsArray[i];
```

It is impossible for an NSArray to contain `int` values. It can contain only *objects*, and in Objective-C an `int` is not an object.

Perhaps you mean

```
int y = [pointsArray[i] intValue];
```

(but I’m just guessing that this NSArray contains NSNumber objects; I have no way of knowing, as you have given no information about that)

Comment: maybe you can also tell me why this is always zero:  int dist = distanceBetweenPoints(middle, topLeft);      int factor = 450/dist;  ....factor is zero for some reason, whilst dist has a value of 350.

Comment: If you have a new question please ask it as a _question_ rather than "leeching" in the comments.